# Sql Server Full Text Search - LastName FirstName searching prob

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a table with many fields out of which LastName and FirstName are two..

This table has around 2 million records..

So I thought of using Full text search.

Now my requirement is to search for a particular record with search criteria LastName and FirstName with combination of LastName and FirstName in the database table

```
..|Firstname    |Lastname     |..
------------------------------------------
  |george walker|bush         |
  |bill         |klinton      |
```

It should return the record if the combination of these two columns contains the extered search criteria

ie., `FirstName=bush` and `LastName=walker`  or
`FirstName=goerge` and `LastName=walker` etc.

I cannot just use like

```
SELECT * FROM TableName where CONTAINS((LastName,FirstName),@LastName)
         and CONTAINS((LastName,FirstName),@FirstName)
```

because searching criteria `FirstName` and `LastName` can be null(SQL SERVER 2008 raises Error) or can have more than one word in it

How to solve the problem?

Comment: please mention the reason for down-vote, if you can't provide an answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName where FirstName IS NOT NULL AND LastName IS NOT NULL (FirstName LIKE '%BUSH%' OR FirstName LIKE '%george%') AND LastName LIKE '%walker%'
```

Try that
Did you want to allow or disallow nulls from results?

Comment: with LIKE predicate I will not be able to make use of Full Text Search and it will be very slow compared to FullText search